# Updating a comma seperated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql

I have the following tables:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[articles](
>   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT [PK_articles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
> (
>   [ID] ASC
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
> ) ON [PRIMARY]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_users](
>   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [GUID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT [PK_test_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
> (
>   [ID] ASC
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
>  CONSTRAINT [unique_guid] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
> (
>   [GUID] ASC
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
> ) ON [PRIMARY]
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[relational](
>   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [articleid] [int] NOT NULL,
>   [userguid] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT [PK_relational] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
> (
>   [ID] ASC
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
> ) ON [PRIMARY]
>
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[relational]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_relational_articles] FOREIGN KEY([articleid])
> REFERENCES [dbo].[articles] ([ID])
>
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[relational] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_relational_articles]
>
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[relational]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_relational_relational] FOREIGN KEY([userguid])
> REFERENCES [dbo].[test_users] ([GUID])
>
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[relational] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_relational_relational]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[seperated](
>   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [userguid] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
>   [articles] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT [PK_seperated] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
> (
>   [ID] ASC
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
> ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[seperated]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_seperated_test_users] FOREIGN KEY([userguid])
> REFERENCES [dbo].[test_users] ([GUID])
>
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[seperated] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_seperated_test_users]
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[test_users] ON 
> INSERT [dbo].[test_users] ([ID], [GUID]) VALUES (1, N'guid1')
> INSERT [dbo].[test_users] ([ID], [GUID]) VALUES (2, N'guid2')
> INSERT [dbo].[test_users] ([ID], [GUID]) VALUES (3, N'guid3')
> INSERT [dbo].[test_users] ([ID], [GUID]) VALUES (4, N'guid4')
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[test_users] OFF
> GO
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test_users]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | GUID 
> -: | :----
>  1 | guid1
>  2 | guid2
>  3 | guid3
>  4 | guid4
> ```

> ```
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[articles] ON 
> INSERT [dbo].[articles] ([ID], [name]) VALUES (1, N'article1')
> INSERT [dbo].[articles] ([ID], [name]) VALUES (2, N'article2')
> INSERT [dbo].[articles] ([ID], [name]) VALUES (3, N'article3')
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[articles] OFF
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM [dbo].[articles]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | name    
> -: | :-------
>  1 | article1
>  2 | article2
>  3 | article3
> ```

> ```
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[relational] ON 
> INSERT [dbo].[relational] ([ID], [articleid], [userguid]) VALUES (1, 1, N'guid1')
> INSERT [dbo].[relational] ([ID], [articleid], [userguid]) VALUES (2, 1, N'guid2')
> INSERT [dbo].[relational] ([ID], [articleid], [userguid]) VALUES (3, 2, N'guid2')
> INSERT [dbo].[relational] ([ID], [articleid], [userguid]) VALUES (4, 1, N'guid3')
> INSERT [dbo].[relational] ([ID], [articleid], [userguid]) VALUES (5, 3, N'guid3')
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[relational] OFF
> GO
> ```

5 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM [dbo].[relational]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | articleid | userguid
> -: | --------: | :-------
>  1 |         1 | guid1   
>  2 |         1 | guid2   
>  3 |         2 | guid2   
>  4 |         1 | guid3   
>  5 |         3 | guid3
> ```

> ```
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[seperated] ON 
> INSERT [dbo].[seperated] ([ID], [userguid], [articles]) VALUES (1, N'guid1', N'1')
> INSERT [dbo].[seperated] ([ID], [userguid], [articles]) VALUES (3, N'guid2', N'1,2')
> INSERT [dbo].[seperated] ([ID], [userguid], [articles]) VALUES (4, N'guid3', N'1,3')
> INSERT [dbo].[seperated] ([ID], [userguid], [articles]) VALUES (5, N'guid4', N'')
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[seperated] OFF
> GO
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM [dbo].[seperated]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | userguid | articles
> -: | :------- | :-------
>  1 | guid1    | 1       
>  3 | guid2    | 1,2     
>  4 | guid3    | 1,3     
>  5 | guid4    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=553f1aa589269482ef9aa5b9e33fb248)*

On the article table there are triggers for insert, delete and update.

- After an insert, records are created in the relational table (only for the new article)
- After an delete, records are removed in the relational table (only for the delete article)
- After an update, records are created/removed (only for the updated article)

Afterwards the seperated table needs to be updated.

For each user there must be exactly 1 record, with comma seperated articles (basically user.guid, SELECT * FROM relational WHERE userguid = user.guid)

At the moment the seperated table gets completely updated using XML FOR PATH, after each insert/delete/update.

However this is no longer a viable option, since this operation is not fast enough (~5 - 10 million records in the relational table)

To fix this, I would like to update the seperated table only for the new/updated/deleted article:

*Inside the trigger I have declared the articleid with @articleId.*

On insert: add ',articleId' or add '@articleId' if the row is empty (cannot be null)
On delete: remove the articleId from all rows
On update: remove when needed and add when needed (depends on what is found in the relational table)

As I basically never work with comma seperated stuff, I have no idea how to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Notes:

- No I cannot do this inside the application as the application that creates the article records cannot connect to the database (it uses some obscure API), and it is also not possible due to the network.
- The amount of inserts, updates and deletes is quite low (thus we can get away with doing this in the trigger)
- I HAVE to use a comma seperated structure, I cannot change the model, as the application that runs on top of this database is a 3rd party application, which we cannot change and neither cannot ask to be modified...
- Yes, these tables are minified, not all columns are here as they do not matter for this question

Comment: Storing multiple values in a comma-delimited string is the wrong way to structure your data.  Fix your data model.

Comment: "You fell victim to one of the classic blunders, the most famous of which is 'Never get involved in a land war in Asia,' but only slightly less well known is this: 'Never put comma-separated data in a column!' "

Comment: Why do you have a table with only one column, which is an identity? Problems with the model aside (you are probably not in a position to change it now, I've been there), can you share some sample data and expected effect?

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

> At the moment the seperated table gets completely updated using XML FOR PATH, after each insert/delete/update.

This make no sense in first glance...

1. if you edit users x,y,z then you should only update these rows in the [seperated] table. I see no explanation why you update all rows.
2. SQL Server is a tabular database and even so it supports unstructured data like XML and JSON, it usually do not perform best when we need to parse the values.

   You have all the data that you need for the [seperated] table in the [relational] table. So there is no sense in parsing each value.

   What do you care what is the current value? if you change the the value (add or remove ID) then simply update the value (string) in the [seperated] table using the information from the [relational] table filter by the userguid which were changed ([using the inserted/deleted logical table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)).

1+2 can be done using "UPDATE FROM SELECT". You can get the list of the IDs using simple query with STRING_AGG function. Do not parse the content, but simply update (replace if you want) and SET the value of the column [articles] for all the rows that were changed (and only these who changed) which where inserted/deleted

> On insert: add ',articleId' or add '@articleId' if the row is empty (cannot be null)
> On delete: remove the articleId from all rows
> On update: remove when needed and add when needed (depends on what is found in the relational table)

Same issue. Do not parse the values for each case. Adding IDs is simple but removing can be more complex. There is no reason to "add" or "remove" anything from the string. Simply update the value of the string to a new value which include all the relevant IDs each time.

Note! If you will provide your code instead of stories then we can provide a working example. You should provide all the queries to reproduce the entire scenario including the triggers and your old and new solutions/attempts

---

---

### Approach 1 (simple solution, best for remove IDs and in some cases for all tasks): UPDATE the rows in [seperated], which were changed in [relational] using the [inserted] and [deleted] tables

In general the query should be something like bellow (remember that this is done AFTER the [relational] table was updated - I read the data from that table and re-create the value of the rows that were changed)

```
-------------------------------------------------- Replace
--> assuming that each user has a row in [seperated] even if no id (as described)

;With NyCTE as (
    SELECT [userguid], SA = STRING_AGG([articleid], ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [articleid] ASC)
    FROM dbo.[relational]
    where userguid in (select userguid from inserted)
    GROUP BY [userguid]
)
UPDATE [seperated] SET articles = NyCTE.SA
FROM[seperated]
INNER JOIN NyCTE ON NyCTE.userguid = [seperated].userguid
GO
--------------------------------------------------
```

---

---

### Approach 2 (Fits only for adding IDs and in most cases it is best approach since we do need to aggregate the [relational] table but only the inserted table): ADDing Ids to existing values of the rows in [seperated], which were changed in [relational] using the [inserted] and [deleted] tables

If you want to use the approach of adding IDs to existing string (remember that SQL Server do not add or edit the string but replace it anyway when we use UPDATE.

```
---------------------------------------------------- Add
;With NyCTE as (
    SELECT [userguid], SA = STRING_AGG([articleid], ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [articleid] ASC)
    FROM dbo.inserted
    where userguid in (select userguid from inserted)
    GROUP BY [userguid]
)
UPDATE [seperated] SET articles = REPLACE(REPLACE('@' + CONCAT (articles,',', SA), '@,', ''), '@', '')
FROM[seperated]
INNER JOIN NyCTE ON NyCTE.userguid = [seperated].userguid
GO
--------------------------------------------------
```

---

---

---------- More Information --------------

### Missing information and clarification

> On the article table there are triggers for insert, delete and update.

Please provide the full code to reproduce the issue (missing the code for the triggers). Always prefer to use code over stories in technical forums.

> At the moment the seperated table gets completely updated using XML FOR PATH

Where is the code?!?

Again, you give stories instead of code.

> Inside the trigger I have declared the articleid with @articleId...

AGAIN! You provide stories instead of sample code. Show us what you do. Provide the code which you tested :-(

It sound like you planing to work with loop which is probably really bad idea, or even worse you plan a solution only to solve one row change. What oi you get 100k rows to insert?!?

The trigger should probably work with the "INSERTED" logical table and use simple JOIN, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT for the task. You should plan the trigger to work on SET of data and not single row.

> On insert: add ',articleId' or add '@articleId' if the row is empty (cannot be null). On delete: remove the articleId from all rows. On update: remove when needed and add when needed (depends on what is found in the relational table)

SQL Server do not "ADD" string to a value in the table. It can only UPDATE the entire value. It can parse the value in advance and then it uses UPDATE and replace the value in the table. As mentioned SQL Server designed for best performance on relational model and not for parsing simple string in a loop.

Note! You should confirm that this is really a new id each time if you want to be safe. If you do this then you got more complex task.